# Merge two array of timelines into one

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, merge, greedy

Hey guys I am currently stuck on a question.

I have to merge to timelines. Each timeline is given as an array of objects.
Currently my thought process was to concat then sort both inputs. After that, compare start and end times. Any help ?

The original question:

Write a function to merge two array timelines into one. If an objects value is different, your new value should be false.

I CREATED THIS TO VISUALLY UNDERSTAND THE QUESTION BETTER:

```
Timeline1:


// null        45                     89                null
// <-----------||---------------------||----------------->
//       true             false                true


Timeline2:
// null                    67                           null
// <-----------------------||---------------------------->
//               true                     false


 MergedTimeline:             
// null        45          67         89                null
// <-----------||----------||---------||----------------->
//       true        false     false       false
```

Example inputs:

```
let timeline1 = [
  { start: null, end: 45, value: true }, 
  { start: 45, end: 89, value: false }, 
  { start: 89, end: null, value: false }
]

let timeline2 = [
  { start: null, end: 67, value: true }, 
  { start: 67, end: null, value: false }
]


//expected output
return [
  { start: null, end: 45, value: true },
  { start: 45, end: 67, value: false },
  { start: 67, end: 89, value: false },
  { start: 89, end: null, value: false }
]
```

Here is my current attempt:

```
    const mergeTimeline = (arr1,arr2) =>{
let combine = arr1.concat(arr2)

let sortedTimeline= combine.sort((a,b)=>{
      return a.start - b.start
    })
const mergedTimeline = [sortedTimeline[0]];

for (let i = 1; i < sortedTimeline.length; i++) {

const currentTimeLine   = sortedTimeline[I];

const lastMergedTime = mergedTimeline[mergedTimeline.length - 1]

  if (lastMergedTime.value !== currentTimeLine.value) {
      currentTimeLine.value = false
      lastMergedTime.end = Math.max(lastMergedTime.end,currentTimeLine.start)
      mergedTimeline.push(currentTimeLine)
    } else{
          mergedTimeline.push(currentTimeLine)

    }

    }
 return mergedTimeline
}
mergeTimeline(timeline1,timeline2)
```

Comment: The original input is always in sorted format right like both the timeline arrays are always sorted right ? , why I am asking because both the timelines start and end with null values.

Comment: @zenwraight it doesn't say, but I would assume they are given to you sorted

Comment: I guess we can also assume the end time in the event object are redundant, right? (can be taken from next event start time). Also, you tag this question with greedy tag - why don't you use greedy approach? I guess it should be better in this case...

Comment: @DavidWinder I did try an greedy approach but I got stuck and I left it as an tag because I do think it might be able to be solved in that manner. you are right the end time do seem redundant